# How to resize screen resolution in Windows 10 guest Virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I have windows 10 as guest PC. Problem is that I can't change window resolution in guest PC.  Guest Addtions are installed but nothing is changed when I choose any of resolutions above 1024*768. I have installed 5.1.6 version of virtual box.

UPDATED: I have restarted my PC and resize screen works fine.

Comment: I don't have a solution to this, but I am having the same experience but with VBox 5.0.26.  This setup worked fine and I could resize things until Windows 10 shoved its auto-update down my throat in the past few days.

Comment: How is this related to programming?